# NUnit integration tests and dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, nunit, castle-windsor, integration-testing

I'm currently making use of Castle Windsor version 2.1 as my container and would like to perform integration tests using the services registered with it.

Currently, I do this my using the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) to retrieve my service instance and perform my integration tests against it as such:

```
var myService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMyService>();
// do stuff with myService
```

What I'd ideally like to do is have my service dependencies injected into my NUnit test fixture automatically. Spring seems to offer [this functionality](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/testing.html#testing-fixture-di), but I can't locate anything similar using Castle.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

I'm sure everyone has (valid) points on whether or not this is a *good* idea; let's just assume that it is in this scenario...Can anyone tell me how this *could* be accomplished using Windsor?

Comment: are your services required for unit testing? have you tried using a mock framework like Moq, or RhinoMocks, or NMock instead? if you really are testing the *integration* between a component and a service, then simply create as many Castle config files as necessary and load them with the XmlConfigurator in your plain or custom Castle container

Comment: @johnny g: I am performing INTEGRATION tests; meaning I don't want to make use of mocks, but the actual services along with all of their actual dependancies. I use mocking in my unit test fixtures as you've suggested.

Comment: eep! that's embarassing - read NUnit and suddenly "saw" unit test everywhere, when clearly you are quite explicit about integration :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're coming to Windsor from Spring/Spring.net you'll find that there are a number of things these projects don't agree on. This is one of them. As a Windsor advocate, I'd never use something like Spring's AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests. Injecting things into a test just seems wrong, but then again, like I said, I'm biased.

If you want to do an integration test, just create a new container instance, add whatever components you need, and run whatever you want to test, e.g:

```
[Test]
public void TestComponentThatDependsOnA() {
  var container = new WindsorContainer();
  container.Register(Component.For<MyComponentA>());
  container.Register(Component.For<ComponentThatDependsOnA>());
  var a = container.Resolve<ComponentThatDependsOnA>();
  var result = a.DoSomething();
  Assert.AreEqual("ok", result);
}
```

If you have registrations neatly wrapped in [installers](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-Installers.ashx) (as you should) you can reuse them in your tests, making tests more concise.

If you have XML config, you can easily load it with Configuration.FromXmlFile().

Also, there is no need to use Common Service Locator here.

Also useful for some integration tests is an [auto-mocking container](http://www.google.com/search?q=windsor+automockingcontainer), which will automatically mock out services (unless you override them with concrete ones, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I am using an installer to wire all my dependancies when the integration test fixture is loaded as you've suggested. I actually perform all of this in a seperate assembly, so the integration test really has no idea that windsor is managing all of this (thus the reason for using the common service locator to retrieve my dependancies). I suppose it could be argued that I'm being lazy with this approach, but my dependency graph is pretty complicated, so this is the only feasible way I could think of to eliminate a ton of setup work for my integration test fixture.

Comment: For reference, I'm using something along these lines to wire up my dependencies: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/11/guywire.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with Castle too. Windsor Installer  is  a generic interface that can be  used to intialize your container/register components. You can then you can implement this interface as many times as you need depending on the context within which the application executes
You can have one installer which injects real objects in a production context and another installer which injects mock objects/test doubles for integration tests.

You can find more information at http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx